# Javascript sticky menu disappears on reload

Tags: javascript

I have a sticky menu that is invisible - then appears on scroll -
but doesnt appear at all when i click to another page or reload - even when i scroll

```
<script>
   $(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    $('.nav').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 500));
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to appear other than when you scroll?  Your handler is only connected to that event.

Comment: it doesnt appear even when i scroll

Comment: That's different from what your question is asking

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked out a solution. It perhaps has something to do with the jquery file having to be called first

even though I only had one file in the header - I had an 'async' declaration in the line

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" async >  
</script>
```

when I removed the 'async' property from my script

```
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"    >  
</script>
```

it seems to be working